# Overriding collection<< method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models `Board` and `Feed` in many-to-many relationship with join :through model `Subscription`.

Lately I added `root_id` field to `Subscription`, and I'd like to setup this field when I do `@board.feeds << @feed` So it would be like `@board.feeds << @feed, root_id: 10`

According to rails docs I can override these methods, but not sure how.

```
def feeds << (??? - how should I setup arguments here? )
  super
  #super creates new Subscription rekord, but how can I access it 
  #to set root_id field?

  #For now let say I accessed it as subscription

  if root_id 
    subscription.root_id = root_id
  else
    subscription.root_id = self.id
  end
  subscription.save
  #return something regular collection << returns
end
```

Comment: Overriding such methods is rarely a good idea. I would just define a method for Subscription like `def add_feed feed` and do all the extra stuff there and use it instead of using `<<`.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `root_id` on `Subscription` represent any aspect of the `Board` or `Feed`? You could maybe do that work in a callback on `Subscription` instead:

```
# Subscription

before_save :assign_root_id

def assign_root_id
  self.root_id = feed.user.id # Whatever root is ....
end
```